# ASP.NET Partial View if Layout is already loaded, else Standard View with default Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to load a view as Partial (one with Layout = null), or as Standard (one with the default Layout in _ViewStart)?

I am trying to accomplish only loading part of a page (Partial View) into the current page if a user is already at some page that has the Layout presented, or loading the whole page (View + Layout) if a user is going to the page are not at a page that has the Layout loaded (such as when entering a specific URL into their address bar).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need to use some javascript too.  Razor is a server-side rendering engine so once it has left the server you'll need client side scripting to take over and respond to your user's clicks if you want to dynamically load portions of the page.

In your View you could have something like this:

```
<button>Load Partial</button>
<div id="partial-content">

</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.get("/ControllerName/MyPartial").success(function(data) {
                $("#partial-content").html(data);
            });
       });
   });
</script>
```

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyPartial()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

The javascript is simple:

Wait for the document to be ready.

Bind to the click event of the button.

When the button is clicked make a HTTP GET request to the url.

When the response comes back set the html of your div.